# Why do I get strange results when I get the Wikipedia API via PHP?

Tags: php, wikipedia

I'm using PHP to access the Wikipedia API. This is the URL I'm getting:

`http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions|links&titles=google&rvprop=ids|timestamp|user|comment|content&rvlimit=1&format=xml`

The results are very strange:

[image: garbled text]

I added `header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the top of the page, but that didn't seem to help. Is this a character encoding issue?

Comment: This sounds like more of a font issue than an encoding problem. What font are you using?

Comment: @Pekka, I use `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your encoding (what you call the "unicode" for some reason) as I can see a few non-latin languages being displayed quite fine. You're just missing the fonts for the four languages you listed.

Comment: what font-family should I set better

Comment: @yuli: It's possible you don't even *have* a font for those. I mean, for instance "iu" is the Inuktituk language, and I'm not sure if anything comes with a font for that by default. Also if you're on a platform that doesn't do font substitution for missing characters (getting missing characters from other fonts), you might be out of luck. At best, you could try using one of those ginormous Unicode fonts that claim to support everything. Not going to work very well on a webpage, though.

Answer (score 0):

Some older versions of php dont support UTF-8 or unicode properly, perhaps ensure you are using an up to date version.